# Check if 3D point is in an equatorial sphere

Tags: geometry, vectors, computational-geometry

I have a question about a 3D check whether a point is inside a smallest possible sphere passing through a triangle $_▵ABC$ (also called equatorial sphere).

The 2D analogy is quite simple:

[2D analogy image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CB6p.png)

$P(px,py)$ is checked whether it is in the smallest circle possible passing through points $A(ax,ay)$ and $B(bx,by)$:

The quickest way to determine this is to check the sign of dot product $\vec{PA}·\vec{PB}$. If the result is negative, then the $cos(α)<0$, which means that $90<α<180$ and point is in the circle.

Now to the 3D example:

What is the quickest way to determine (preferably a similar way with vectors) if point $P(px,py,pz)$ is in the smallest sphere possible passing through points $A(ax,ay,az)$, $B(bx,by,bz)$, $C(cx,cy,cz)$?:

[3D example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diMc1.png)

Thanks in advance for comments, hope I was clear enough.

Comment: @A.Goodier thanks, edited

Comment: In your description of the 2-D case, if $\overrightarrow{PA} \cdot \overrightarrow{PB}$ is positive, then surely $0 < \cos \alpha \le 1$ and $0 < \alpha \le \pi / 2$ which makes the point _outside_ the circle?

Comment: @PaulAljabar dang it, I messed it up. You're correct, I'll fix it...

Comment: Yep, now it makes sense.

Comment: Must the three points lie on the sphere? The smallest enclosing sphere might only have two of the points on it, just as in the plane, the circumcircle of a triangle isn’t necessarily the smallest enclosing circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an outline of a method that should work.

The sphere is the smallest one containing points $A$, $B$ and $C$. The intersection of this sphere and the plane containing the points gives the circumcircle of the triangle $ABC$. In other words, the centre of the sphere is centre of the circumcircle of the triangle $ABC$.

Find the coordinates of the centre $O$ using the formula [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle#Higher_dimensions).

Now find a point at the opposite end of a diameter for the sphere starting at, say, $A$. It's coordinates can be obtained by adding $2 \overrightarrow{AO}$ to the coordinates of $A$. Call this new point $A'$.

Now you can repeat your 2-D test using the points $A$, $A'$ and $P$.

Comment: Thank you! I'll accept the answer, I will try the code implementation later. However, I had a thought a few minutes ago, couldn't one just do three 2D tests (as shown in question) in XY, XZ, YZ planes and see if every test is true? I wonder which solution would be quicker to compute.

Comment: @ArūnasRimkus Very doubtful that testing against projections of the points onto the coordinate planes will work. Your 2-d test only uses two of the three vertices, so which ones would you choose? Moreover, the disc defined by the circumcircle of the projected vertices isn’t the projection of the sphere.

Comment: Once you have the circumcenter $O$, comparing $OA^2=\overrightarrow{OA}\cdot\overrightarrow{OA}$ to $OP^2=\overrightarrow{OP}\cdot\overrightarrow{OP}$ is faster. The original 2-D method is faster than the obvious one because it saves a few additions and divisions by 2 by not computing the midpoint of the segment—the center of the circle—but if you already have that, then using it is also just two dot products and a comparison. Computing the antipode of $A$ here is extra work.

Comment: Also, using barycentric coordinates to find the circumcenter might be faster than the directly-linked method. In 3-D, by my rough count it only requires about half as many multiplications, about the same number of adds, but two more divisions.

Comment: Thanks @amd, all good points.

Comment: @amd Thanks for pointing it out, typical of me to rush something without actually thinking too much. But how does the comparison of $OA^2=\vec{OA}\cdot\vec{OA}$ to $OP^2=\vec{OP}\cdot\vec{OP}$ work? What does it give to us?
Is there also a possible way to actually **avoid** the search for circumcenter $O$ in the first place?

Comment: @ArūnasRimkus $OA$ is the radius of the sphere, $OP$ the distance from the sphere’s center to the test point. The point is inside the sphere iff $OP\le OA$.

Comment: @ArūnasRimkus  I haven’t come up with anything faster than this. Directly computing an antipode of one of the vertices is no faster, and I haven’t thought of any reliable tests that use only the vertices. If you’re testing several points against a fixed triangle, this is likely to be fastest since the incremental cost per point is a dot product and comparison. If the triangle isn’t fixed, but you expect that most of the time the point will be too far away, using a quicker reject for those points and then reverting to this method could give you an overall speed improvement.